# Keeping view size proportional

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I have a container `View` and it has a static height, lets say 50:

```
container: {
  width: '100%',
  height: 50,
}
```

Now this container has one child, that takes the whole parent's height, by setting its height to `100%`:

```
child: {
  height: 100%,
}
```

I want this child element to be ideal square, with the same width as its height automatically, so if tomorrow i will change parent' height to 60 
then child height will auto grow (because of `height: 100%`) but how can i set its width to fit itself automatically? `width: 'auto'` doesn't have any effect..

[image]

Playground: https://snack.expo.io/SkSWxPKbZ

Answer (score 7):

`aspectRatio: 1` does the trick, like:

```
child: {
  height: '100%',
  aspectRatio: 1
}
```

This way the child will always take 100% of parent' height and its width will be exactly as its height.

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/SkWzrCYZ-

Answer (score 1):

PlayGround : https://snack.expo.io/SkED1_YZ-

This is just the simplest way to achieve it. I used a constant to store the height of the main hence it can be used as the width of the inner view.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the availableHeight dynamically and set the width to the same value:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    availableHeight: 0,
  }
}


render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View 
        style={{ 
          flex: 1, 
          width: this.state.availableHeight,
        }} 
        onLayout={(e) => {
          const { height } = e.nativeEvent.layout;
          this.setState({availableHeight: height});
        }}>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have found a way to do it on style level.